# How to remove the duplicate data from csv file?

Tags: r, csv, duplicates

I have data about baseball result in 2016.

[image: Example]

Now, I want to remove the column that made tie score.

That is, I want to remove the column that has same value in $team1_score and $team2_score.

How can I use the function in r?

I just tried to use the following code, but it didn't work well.

```
Baseball2 <- Baseball[!duplicated(Baseball$team1_score)]
```

Please help me...!!

Comment: what went wrong...

Comment: Why is it today that everybody is posting *images of data*? Please, Hailey, post **data**, not an image of it. Please read (or reread) about [reproducible questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), especially areas where it provides options for including usable data in your question.

Comment: ... and in this problem, you'll need to identify what the intended output should be. Removing a whole column does not make sense to me. And since none of this data shows duplication in teams/scores, it seems insufficient to demonstrate your point.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is on dealing with duplicated data. Suggest to remove `duplicates` tag and revise the question title.

Comment: I've never uploaded any actual file, so that is why I just captured and uploaded the image. There are so many data like above image and a few scores were tie in above data. I just wanted to remove the column that has tie score .

Answer (score 0):

Here's an simple way to remove rows with tie-score:

```
(dat <- data.frame(Team1_Score= c(1,2,3), Team2_Score=c(2,3,3)))

  Team1_Score Team2_Score
1           1           2
2           2           3
3           3           3
```

Use logical test to find which row has tie score:

```
tie <- dat$Team1_Score == dat$Team2_Score
tie
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Use this result to select rows that are not tie:

```
dat[!tie, ]

  Team1_Score Team2_Score
1           1           2
2           2           3
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you do not want to remove duplicates, but need to subset the dataframe discarding tied matches.

A very simple option using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
Baseball2 <- data.table(Baseball)
Baseball2 <- Baseball2[Team1_Score != Team2_Score,]
```